# Javascript - Regex. Replace all spaces in a string, but called from a function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function which I use to replace characters within strings, but doesn't work in all circumstances.
I want to replace spaces with nulls and it's not working.

```
function fncReplaceAll(pString, pOld, pNew) {  
//
// Replace all occurences of a string with a new string.
//
return pString.replace(new RegExp(pOld, 'g'),pNew);
}
```

It's called like this:

```
fncReplaceAll(pPart,'/\s/',''))
```

I've also tried

```
fncReplaceAll(pPart,' ',''))
```

And

```
fncReplaceAll(pPart,'[ ]+',''))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function fncReplaceAll(pString, pOld, pNew) {
        return pString.replace(new RegExp(pOld, 'g'), pNew);
    }
    alert(fncReplaceAll(pPart, '\\s', ''));
```

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDfcj/)

Comment: Thanks. I've realised that the function was working OK and I had another problem with a subsequent function encoding the string.